# How is the "adjoint representation" related to generic group representations?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, adjoint-operators

I'm studying representation theory in order to have a basis to study quantum field theory.

I think the text (my professor's) i'm studying on is pretty confusing. 
I don't really get the difference between the representation of a group and its adjoint representation.

What I understood is that the A. Representation consists of nxn matrices, where n is the group dimension. But I thought this was also for any representation of the group, because on this text they are always written as matrices.

Thank you very much

Comment: Long story short: a square is a rectangle, but not all rectangles are squares.  The A. representation is **a representation**, but not all representations are the A. representation.

Answer (score 0):

The adjoint representation is an *example* of a representation of a group, but it's not the *only* representation; it is one of many.  In fact, a common thing to do with Lie groups is to classify all possible representations (or at least the irreducible ones, up to isomorphism).

For example, the adjoint representation of $SL_2$ is made out of $3 \times 3$ matrices.  However, we can make a representation (in fact, an [irreducible representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_SL2(R))) of this group with $n \times n$ matrices for any $n$.

Comment: ok thank you, much clearer :)